# TableLayoutPanel and AutoScroll

Tags: c#, tablelayoutpanel, autoscroll

I have a TableLayoutPanel to which I add rows dynamically.
Each row has an absolute size.
I set the AutoScroll to "true", but when I add rows that go out of the display of the TableLayoutPanel, I don't see the scroll.

This is the designer code:

```
namespace WindowsFormsApplication1
{
    partial class Form1
    {
        /// <summary>
        /// Required designer variable.
        /// </summary>
        private System.ComponentModel.IContainer components = null;

        /// <summary>
        /// Clean up any resources being used.
        /// </summary>
        /// <param name="disposing">true if managed resources should be disposed; otherwise, false.</param>
        protected override void Dispose(bool disposing)
        {
            if (disposing && (components != null))
            {
                components.Dispose();
            }
            base.Dispose(disposing);
        }

        #region Windows Form Designer generated code

        /// <summary>
        /// Required method for Designer support - do not modify
        /// the contents of this method with the code editor.
        /// </summary>
        private void InitializeComponent()
        {
            this.tableLayoutPanel1 = new System.Windows.Forms.TableLayoutPanel();
            this.button1 = new System.Windows.Forms.Button();
            this.SuspendLayout();
            // 
            // tableLayoutPanel1
            // 
            this.tableLayoutPanel1.AutoScroll = true;
            this.tableLayoutPanel1.CellBorderStyle = System.Windows.Forms.TableLayoutPanelCellBorderStyle.Single;
            this.tableLayoutPanel1.ColumnCount = 1;
            this.tableLayoutPanel1.ColumnStyles.Add(new System.Windows.Forms.ColumnStyle(System.Windows.Forms.SizeType.Percent, 50F));
            this.tableLayoutPanel1.Location = new System.Drawing.Point(24, 48);
            this.tableLayoutPanel1.Name = "tableLayoutPanel1";
            this.tableLayoutPanel1.RowCount = 1;
            this.tableLayoutPanel1.RowStyles.Add(new System.Windows.Forms.RowStyle(System.Windows.Forms.SizeType.Percent, 50F));
            this.tableLayoutPanel1.Size = new System.Drawing.Size(239, 163);
            this.tableLayoutPanel1.TabIndex = 0;
            // 
            // button1
            // 
            this.button1.Location = new System.Drawing.Point(24, 10);
            this.button1.Name = "button1";
            this.button1.Size = new System.Drawing.Size(239, 28);
            this.button1.TabIndex = 1;
            this.button1.Text = "button1";
            this.button1.UseVisualStyleBackColor = true;
            this.button1.Click += new System.EventHandler(this.button1_Click);
            // 
            // Form1
            // 
            this.AutoScaleDimensions = new System.Drawing.SizeF(6F, 13F);
            this.AutoScaleMode = System.Windows.Forms.AutoScaleMode.Font;
            this.ClientSize = new System.Drawing.Size(292, 266);
            this.Controls.Add(this.button1);
            this.Controls.Add(this.tableLayoutPanel1);
            this.Name = "Form1";
            this.Text = "Form1";
            this.ResumeLayout(false);

        }

        #endregion

        private System.Windows.Forms.TableLayoutPanel tableLayoutPanel1;
        private System.Windows.Forms.Button button1;
    }
}
```

and this is how I add rows:

```
using System.Text;
using System.Windows.Forms;

namespace WindowsFormsApplication1
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            tableLayoutPanel1.RowCount++;
            tableLayoutPanel1.RowStyles.Add(new RowStyle(SizeType.Absolute, 30));
            Button b = new Button();
            tableLayoutPanel1.Controls.Add(b, 0, tableLayoutPanel1.RowCount - 1);

        }
    }
}
```

Does anybody know what's going on?
thanks :)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Set the AutoScroll property to True.

Make sure that the default rows that get added by the designer do not cause any trouble.  Make your constructor look like this:

```
    public Form1() {
        InitializeComponent();
        tableLayoutPanel1.RowCount = 0;
        tableLayoutPanel1.RowStyles.Clear();
        tableLayoutPanel1.AutoScroll = true;
    }
```

Answer (score 2):

Looks like you're missing tableLayoutPanel.AutoSize = true.

Comment: Thanks for this additional comment. It helped me. Indeed if you want a tablelayoutpanel to scroll inside a winform, you need to set both the autoscroll and autosize to true, and -off course- make sure the combined height of the rows in the tablelayoutpanel exeed the form's height.

Answer (score 1):

Try the below line which may work for you:

```
this.tableLayoutPanel1.AutoScroll = true;
this.tableLayoutPanel1.Dock = DockStyle.Top;
```